# How to select a character in QTextEdit

Tags: qt

I want to select a single character in a QTextEdit widget and then change it's format. But I found that select() funciton only support 4 types: **Document**, **BlockUnderCursor**, **LineUnderCursor** and **WordUnderCursor**.

So, is there any other way can only select a char?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `select(..)` method for `QTextEdit` in either Qt 4.8 or 5.0 (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit-members.html, https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit-members.html).

Comment: Please post the code you've tried thus far.

Comment: sorry for my unclear description, select() actually is a method of QTextCursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [QTextCursor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html) for this

Assuming you know the position of the character you want to select as (`charPosition`)

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui_->textEdit->textCursor();
cursor.setPosition(charPosition);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Right, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
ui_->textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```